# Android Studio Login Token Request Error using Retrofit and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, http, retrofit, sharedpreferences

A token is sent to the client when I login, so I'm going to use the retrofit library to take the token and include it in the header of the request and send the data to the server.

When I login, I want to save data through the SharedPreferences library to store tokens delivered to the client locally.

**But there is error :**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.todo_android, PID: 7323
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:217)
                                                                                                        at com.example.todo_android.MainActivity.saveData(MainActivity.kt:30)
                                                                                                        at com.example.todo_android.Screen.LoginScreenKt$sendLogin$1.onResponse(LoginScreen.kt:64)
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Actually When I login only with body json without Header and SharedPreferences, its working and it gives me token and resultCode.

```
resultCode : 200
token : e91389ca537f481d1937a43c49da0d5b827e5cfd
```

There is code:

**Login Model**

```
package com.example.todo_android.Data.Profile

data class Login(
    val email: String,
    val password: String
    )
```

**LoginRequest**

```
package com.example.todo_android.Request.ProfileRequest

import com.example.todo_android.Data.Profile.Login
import com.example.todo_android.Response.ProfileResponse.LoginResponse
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface LoginRequest {
    @POST("/account/login/")
    fun requestLogin(
//        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Body loginRequest: Login
    ) : Call<LoginResponse>
}
```

**LoginResponse**

```
package com.example.todo_android.Response.ProfileResponse

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class LoginResponse(
    @SerializedName("resultCode")
    val resultCode: String,
    @SerializedName("token")
    val token: String
)



**LoginScreen**

package com.example.todo_android.Screen

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.PasswordVisualTransformation
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.todo_android.Data.Profile.Login
import com.example.todo_android.MainActivity
import com.example.todo_android.Navigation.Action.RouteAction
import com.example.todo_android.Navigation.NAV_ROUTE
import com.example.todo_android.R
import com.example.todo_android.Request.ProfileRequest.LoginRequest
import com.example.todo_android.Response.ProfileResponse.LoginResponse
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

fun goCalendar(route: NAV_ROUTE, routeAction: RouteAction) {
    routeAction.navTo(route)
}

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
fun sendLogin(email: String, password: String, routeAction: RouteAction) {

    var loginResponse: LoginResponse? = null

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://plotustodo-ctzhc.run.goorm.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var loginRequest: LoginRequest = retrofit.create(LoginRequest::class.java)

    loginRequest.requestLogin(Login(email, password)).enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {

        //실패할 경우
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("LOGIN", t.message.toString())
        }

        //성공할 경우
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
            loginResponse = response.body()

            when (loginResponse?.resultCode) {
                "200" -> {
                    goCalendar(NAV_ROUTE.CALENDAR, routeAction)

                    Log.d("LOGIN", "resultCode : " + loginResponse?.resultCode)
                    Log.d("LOGIN", "token : " + loginResponse?.token)
                    Log.d("LOGIN", "메인 화면으로 갑니다.")

                    MainActivity().saveData(loginResponse?.token.toString())
                }
                "500" -> {
                    Log.d("LOGIN", "non_field_errors:[Check Your Email or Password]")
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(routeAction: RouteAction) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    )
    {
        var email by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        var password by remember { mutableStateOf("") }


        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.width(300.dp),
            value = email,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                Color(0xff9E9E9E),
                disabledLabelColor = Color(0xff9E9E9E),
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            singleLine = true,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
            onValueChange = {
                email = it
            })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.width(300.dp),
            value = password,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                Color(0xff9E9E9E),
                disabledLabelColor = Color(0xffE9E9E9),
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            singleLine = true,
            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
            onValueChange = {
                password = it
            })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp))
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(300.dp)
                .height(50.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFBE3C7)),
            onClick = { sendLogin(email, password, routeAction) }
        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.login), color = Color.Black)
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.todo_android

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import com.example.todo_android.Navigation.NavigationGraph
import com.example.todo_android.ui.theme.TodoandroidTheme

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TodoandroidTheme {
                NavigationGraph()
            }
        }
        loadData()
    }


    fun loadData() {
        val pref = getSharedPreferences("UserTokenKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) // UserTokenKey: 파일명
        val token = pref.getString("Token", "")
    }

    fun saveData(token: String) {
        val pref = getSharedPreferences("UserTokenKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) // UserTokenKey: 파일명
        val edit = pref.edit()
        edit.putString("Token", token) // "Token"라는 이름을 사용하여 token값을 입력한다.
        edit.commit()
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me which part was implemented incorrectly and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the log, the exact problem is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:217)
  at com.example.todo_android.MainActivity.saveData(MainActivity.kt:30)
  at com.example.todo_android.Screen.LoginScreenKt$sendLogin$1.onResponse(LoginScreen.kt:64)
```

which points to this line

```java
MainActivity().saveData(loginResponse?.token.toString())
```

You cannot instantiate a new `MainActivity` class in order to call the function `saveData()`. The `Context` used to call `getSharedPreferences()` will be `null` if your `MainActivity` is created like that.

So you can try if the following options address the problem:

1. Make your `saveData()` as a `callback` function, pass it to the necessary class to call
2. Pass `Context` to the class you need to call `getSharedPreferences()`, and call it like `Context.getSharedPreferences()`